# Play framework, How to send HTTP GET/POST request to another site

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a controller that should execute the request to another site and get a response. How to do it?

```
@Singleton
class MeController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents, actorSystem: ActorSystem)(implicit exec: ExecutionContext) extends AbstractController(cc) {


  def message = Action.async {

    val url = "https://another.site/data"
    val httpRequest = ???

    Future(httpRequest.response.body).map { msg => Ok(msg) }

  }

}
```

Comment: use a HTTP client - Play has one: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaWS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Calling REST APIs with Play WS](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaWS)

Comment: use comments for links